# URL redirection from wordpress to sharepoint

Tags: wordpress, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a Wordpress site which has url A- http://xyz.abc.com. I have also created a SharePoint site with url B- http://abc.def.com/ghi. Now I want all my users who go to url A to be redirected to url B. Can anyone give me some pointers to achieve this.

The OLD site is deleted so cannot do anything in OLD site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do add redirection by using below wordpress plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

or

you need to add below code to your deleted site .htaccess file

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L] 
</IfModule>`

Comment: The OLD site is deleted so cannot do anything in OLD site.

Comment: you need to add below code to your deleted site .htaccess file
 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

</IfModule>